# Menu not appearing before scrolling

Tags: wordpress, menu, background, styling

When I go on to my website www.croiativefilms.ie the menu is not there until I start scrolling. Or its there but I can't seem to find the option to change the background of the menu. Not sure which. I am using ZK Monaco V1.6.1 theme

Comment: We'll need some more details about the site. Is this a theme builder, pre-built theme or a custom theme?

Comment: I am using ZK Monaco V1.6.1 theme @NickG.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on `ZK Monaco` in the WordPress admin menu and then select `Header`, there's an option to set the Header background-color.

For future reference, here's the [ZK Monaco documentation](https://spyropress.com/docs/monaco/).

[image: Theme Options]

[image: Header Options]